# How can i run MEKA GUI on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, weka

I'm trying to launch the GUI file of MEKA (an extension to weka) and it's manual tells me to execute a file called: `run.bat`. the file has the following content:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET MEMORY=1256m 
SET MAIN=meka.gui.guichooser.GUIChooser 
java -Xmx%MEMORY% -cp ".\lib\*" %MAIN% %1
```

once i click it a cmd window appear for second and dispear rapidly and the GUI doesn't appear. How can i solve this problem, knowing that i'e tried to execute the file as Adminstrator but the same problem

Comment: Go to the folder that the batch file is in, then hold shift and right click. A popup menu will appear, find and click 'Open Console Window Here'. Then type 'run.bat'. This will make the output stay on screen. From there please post what you see. Otherwise we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: @Duphus thank you for the answer, it appear: 
Java is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: This means that your computer either a: doesn't have java installed or b: Java isn't in your computers PATH. To solve this, edit the batch to have the following line at the top: 'set /p path=[path to java];%path%' But replace '[path to java]'  with the location of your java install (on my computer: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin, however yours may differ). If it still doesn't work, install the latest version of Java through the proper channels.